# Regex on Data Anotations

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a regex on an MVC3 model, which requires to check the first character of a string to ensure it starts with a zero, follow by another 6 numbers, this is what I have:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^0", ErrorMessage = "value must start with a zero.")]
```

no matter what I type in the field it returns the error message:

```
1 = error
0 = error
0000000 = error message
```

Any Ideas here

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't make sense, post your view please.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^0[\d]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "Value must start with a zero.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, the following works fine for me:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^0[0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "value must start with a zero.")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Value)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```